# Git - Using an alias instead of full repository path

Tags: git

If I create a git server repository in /opt/git/test.git, is there any way that I can set it up so that users can access the repository like...

```
git clone git@host:/git/test.git
```

instead of

```
git clone git@host:/opt/git/test.git
```

In other words I don't want the users to have to use the full path to the repository. This seems like it should be a straightforward thing to do, and I know it can be done with svn, but I just can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you're using to serve the repos, but it's a pretty sure thing that every server has an equivalent for `git-daemon --base-path=/opt`